# c# downloading file with WebClient and saving it

Tags: c#

I have the code to download the file, It only replaces it.

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    {
          webClient.DownloadFile("http://test.png", "C:\PNG.png")
    }
```

I only wonder, would it be possible to Download the file, then save the file instead of replacing the old file (in the example above, png.png).

Comment: You are saving it with the same name to the same location which will replace it each time. Just use a different name.

Comment: Before you download it, check if it exists.  If it doesn't download it.  If it does do something different (use a different name)

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about that.

Comment: @MarshallOfSound This approach may get you into trouble. Just think of two threads using this approach for larger files. The first thread sees that there is no file named like, starts the download and afterwards the second thread comes into play, sees that there is no file names like (yet - since thread 1 did not complete the download) and then starts the download with the very file name.

Comment: Then make a placeholder file before the download starts. With that filename but completely empty

Answer (score 5):

Create a unique name each time.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://test.png", string.Format("C:\{0}.png", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Stephens answer is perfectly valid this may be unhandy sometimes. I'd suppose to create a temporary filename (which is not that different from what Stephen proposed, but in a temporary folder - most likely AppData/Local/Temp) and rename the file after the download is complete. This class demonstrates the idea and I've not verified that it works as intended, but if it does feel free to use the very class.

```
class CopyDownloader
{
    public string RemoteFileUrl { get; set; }
    public string LocalFileName { get; set; }
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    public CopyDownloader()
    {
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClientOnDownloadFileCompleted;
    }

    public void StartDownload()
    {
        var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        webClient.DownloadFile(RemoteFileUrl, tempFileName, tempFileName)
    }

    private void WebClientOnDownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs asyncCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        string tempFileName = asyncCompletedEventArgs.UserState as string;
        File.Copy(tempFileName, GetUniqueFileName());
    }

    private string GetUniqueFilename()
    {
        // Create an unused filename based on your original local filename or the remote filename
    }
}
```

If you'd like to display the progress you might expose an event, which is emitted when `WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged` is thrown

```
class CopyDownloader
{
    public event DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;

    private void WebClientOnDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs downloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if(ProgressChanged != null)
        {
            ProgressChanged(this, downloadProgressChangedEventArgs);
        }
    }

    public CopyDownloader()
    {
         webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClientOnDownloadFileCompleted;
         webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientOnDownloadProgressChanged;
    }

    // ...
}
```