# Download CSV file from website

Tags: c#, csv

```
        string formUrl = "url";
        string formParams = string.Format("params");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        string pageSource;
        string getUrl = "link to csv file";
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Hey guys I am currently using this code which I got off this website, I have downloaded fiddler and was able to login and navigate to the page where I want to download my .csv file.

The StreamReader does bring back what is inside the .csv file but I would like to download it to a path on my computer.

The getUrl is a link directly going to what I would click to download the file in a browser.

> example of the URL:
>   http://myurl.com/index.php?controller=AdminRequestSql&token=123&id_request_sql=7&exportrequest_sql=1

Sorry if this isn't worded correctly I am quite new to C# and trying to learn new things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET framework 4 and above:

```
    string formUrl = "url";
    string formParams = string.Format("params");
    string cookieHeader;
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

    string pageSource;
    string getUrl = "link to csv file";
    WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
    getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
    WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new 
    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("filename.csv"))
    using (Stream input = getResponse.Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
         input.CopyTo(output);
    }
```

For .NET framework lower than 4

```
    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("filename.csv"))
    using (Stream input = getResponse.Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
         int bytesLength;
         while ((bytesLength = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
         {
              output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLength);
         }
    }
```

The difference between the two is that you need to download the files manually for the lower frameworks. Additionally, using the `WebClient` class is recommended for this. You can find tonnes of resources on how to use that class. For now, you can get started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649294/c-sharp-downloading-file-with-webclient-and-saving-it).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't use your code but I followed your link and was able to use the WebClient.Downloadfile.

Thanks a lot!